# Android Thread Issues

Tags: android

I'm having some problems running a thread in my android application, It should show a dialog asking the user something and if the user clicks yes, a loading dialog should appear while it's doing something in the background, I created a thread but when I click the yes button, the UI still locks up until the process is done.

Code:
Dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            builder.setMessage("LOGO.bin Was Not Found, Would You Like To Extract It?")
                    .setTitle("LOGO Not Found!");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                 getAndExtract();


                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   finish();
                   System.exit(0);
                }
            });


            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

getAndExtract:

```
 public void getAndExtract()
{

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    showLoad("Grabbing Logo...");

                    getLogo();
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    progressDialog.cancel();

                    showLoad("Extracting Images...");
                    extractImages();
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }catch (InterruptedException iE)
                {
                    iE.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).run();




}
```

showLoad:

```
progressDialog.setMessage(msg);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.show();
```

basics of extractImages:

```
Command cmd = new Command(0, "LogoInjector -i " + getFilesDir() + "/LOGO.bin -d -g " + getFilesDir() + "/");

RootTools.getShell(true).add(cmd);
```

basics of getLogo:

```
Command cmd = new Command(0, "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p" + partitionIndex + " of=" + getFilesDir() + "/LOGO.bin");

RootTools.getShell(true).add(cmd);
```

I also tried putting showLoad in runOnUiThread but there was no change... if I remove progressDialog.cancel(); it does show the loading dialog but after the extract is already complete. I press Yes and it just hangs until getLogo() and extractImages() both completed

Can anyone help me find out why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using AsyncTask() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using AsyncTask:

```
    final AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // do whatever you need to do in background

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute( aVoid);

            // do after finished 
        }
    };
    asyncTask.execute();
```

Hope that helps =]